# Is it possible to inherit a python file inside a custom class?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to do something like this:

```
class MyPyplot(matplotlib.pyplot):

    def __init__(self, data, name):
        self.name = name
        self.data = data
        # Other setup stuff

myPlot1 = MyPyplot(data, "Something v Soemthing")
myPlot1.title("New title")
```

I would like to be able to create multiple instances of `pyplot` in each class `MyPyplot`.

I know I can just do `figure` to create another graph, but that isn't my exact goal. I want a class of type `pyplot` so I can keep them all separate to their own variable name. I also would like to add some functions to the `pyplot` without modifying `pyplot` directly.

Comment: `matplotlib.pyplot` is a module, not a class. You cannot inherit from it.

Comment: You may want to inherit from `matplotlib.figure.Figure` instead. See https://matplotlib.org/api/index.html for a quick discussion about the difference between the API provided by `pyplot` and the object-oriented API that `pyplot` wraps.

Comment: Thank you @chepner. I am going to try `matplotlib.figure.Figure`. The second I posted this the idea came to me. I'll post back later.